# How to add spaces in mathjax table cell?

Tags: google-colaboratory, mathjax

In Google Colaboratory I can make a table using mathjax embedded in markdown. But spaces between words, e.g. `table header`, disappear when the code is rendered.

```
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & table header & table header & table header \\ \hline
table content & table content & table content & table content\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
```

This code is rendered like this:

[image: table with words without space between them]

How do I add spaces between words of a table cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `& \text{table header} &` in each cell. Seems the cells are default to math-mode, which removes spaces.

Comment: If this works for you, I would appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: I also discovered `\;` for white space,  so `table\;header` although this also works